# Azure Mobile Service not working on Cordova, browser

Tags: cordova, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating Cordova app and it accesses azure with mobile service client.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services

iOS and Android works fine but Chrome doesn't.

```
$ cordova emulate browser
```

The app stops at the following code.

```
azureClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(
            azureMobileServiceURL,
            azureMobileAccessToken
        );
```

Does anyone have any hint?
I appreciate any help.

**EDIT**

I'm currently using com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services 1.2.9.

And I checked chrome console and the following error was displayed.
This means the program cannot refer to the plugin, doesn't it?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WindowsAzure is not defined
```

Azure Mobile Service Screen Shot
[image: Azure Mobile Service Screen Shot]

Comment: What have you set up on the Azure side?  Have you set up an Azure Mobile Service or Azure App Service Mobile App?  What version of the plugin are you using?  Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @AdrianHall thank you for your reply. I added information you asked. Please check it.

Comment: Yes - your application is not able to see WindowsAzure, which is from the plugin.  Ensure you are not referring to the plugin until the onDeviceReady event has fired - it isn't available until then.  LMK if that fixes it for you and I will propose the answer.

Comment: @AdrianHall Thanks for your reply.  I'm sure WindowsAzure plugin is called after onDeviceReady event. Does the plugin work on Chrome?

Comment: Yes - I use the Ripple emulator as a test environment with Chrome.   I suspect that you are running into a specific browser issue since it works on the emulators.